# Essentials for building a RTS

Tags: rts, planning

I was wondering if anyone had any links to good reads or books in regards to things to think about when developing a RTS game, I would have been reading things like [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160115234655/http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/RTS_Design_Guide) and [this](http://www.oxeyegames.com/category/rts-design/) but would like to read more into it.

Also I have development experience and soon would like to start building the skeleton myself but if anyone has any additional articles about the process (not in programming, but more on planning) that would be great help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could read some Gamasutra features. That's usually a good source of information, from people that actually ship games:

- [The Design of *StarCraft II*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132562/the_design_of_starcraft_ii.php)
- [*StarCraft II*: Building On The Beta](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/134199/starcraft_ii_building_on_the_beta.php)
- [1500 Archers on a 28.8: Network Programming in Age of Empires and Beyond](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php)
- [Successful Playtesting In *Swords & Soldiers*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/134311/successful_playtesting_in_swords__.php)
- [Postmortem: Ronimo Games' *Swords & Soldiers*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132618/postmortem_ronimo_games_swords__.php)
- [The End of RTS? A *Command & Conquer 4* Interview](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132691/the_end_of_rts_a_command__.php)
- etc.