# Real-Time-Strategy control structures/achitecture

Tags: architecture, rts

I am looking at building a real time strategy game (of at least the framework for one) in Unity, and was wondering what control structures and/or architecture I should focus on using.

current expectations:
I think that I will need a global controller/registry architecture, with sub controllers for the different players while considering the AI controller(s) to be player(s), and then registries for the different groups.

how does my current design logic hold.

additionally are there any specific resources that I should look through to achieve this goal?

Comment: This seems like a really broad, unfocused question.

Comment: @TrevorPowell I am asking for what architecture and/or control structures would best serve a Real Time Strategy game. by refining the question farther it may dilute it from being generally used. perhaps pointing to resources would still be beneficial.

Comment: See the [FAQ] : Specifically, that "how to make (or start making) a particular type of game" is off-topic. Additionally, "your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Since you already have a plan, you should probably just go with that. Then if you run into problems, post questions asking about the problems. Also, [a possible duplicate question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27529/essentials-for-building-a-rts) (which should probably also be closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despitethe fact that your Question is verry unprecice i will give it a shot.

First, you should get familiar with the concept of Entity Component Systems:
[Using component based entity system practically](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/using-component-based-entity-system-practically)

Then you should learn what exactly the command pattern is, because it is by far the most usefull in rts games and multiplayer games:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

This should give you a better view on what the next questions are you need to ask.

Comment: thank you for at least trying to answer the question, and at least giving me something to consider/go on. though some may feel your answer "too specific" for a "vague" question.